# Text manipulation of a comma separated string in python

Tags: python, file, text, nlp

I want to read a textfile `test.txt` where the txt is in the format

```
'Jon, Stacy, Simon, ..., Maverick'
```

I'd want to save the string into `test2.txt` as

```
'Jon AS t1_Jon, Stacy AS t1_Stacy, Simon AS t1_Simon, ..., Maverick AS t1_Maverick'
```

It could be that there is a linebreak every now and then, I would want to ignore that. How would I do it in an efficient and easy way?

PS: I couldn't come up with a more fitting title, how would you name it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One nice approach is to use the re module.

```
import re

s_in = 'apple, banana, orange,\n mango, guava'
words = re.split(r'[,\n]\s*',s_in)
s_out = ', '.join([f'{word} AS t1_{word}' for word in words])
print(s_out)
```

Result:

```
apple AS t1_apple, banana AS t1_banana, orange AS t1_orange, mango AS t1_mango, guava AS t1_guava
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, my question was probably missleading. Each word is different from each other. So its not really 'word1, word2', but more like 'Jon, Stacy, Maverick, ...'

Comment: Right, the code works with that assumption. I've changed the example; see my edit

Comment: Just noticed that it's always `t1_`; I had that incrementing before. See latest edit.

Comment: thanks!! sorry for the missleading description!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out

```
with open('test.txt') as f:

_lines = ''
for line in f.readlines():
    words = line.split(',')
    for word in words:
        _word = f'{word} AS t1_{word}'
        _lines +=_word
        
    _lines +='\n'
    
print(_lines)
```

Result

```
Jon AS t1_Jon Stacy AS t1_ Stacy Simon AS t1_ Simon ... AS t1_ ... Maverick
 AS t1_ Maverick
```

Comment: thanks! that would work